# how to make triangle using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create the hollow triangle pattern in python 2.7 like this

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
* * * * *
```

I think I can use loop code

```
line = 5
for i in range (line):
    print (line-i) * " " + (line+1) * "* "
```

but the output is

```
    *
   * *
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Anyone help me to make hollow triangle?
Thank you.

Comment: @ps06756 yes, would you help me?

Comment: There are good answers to your questions. Moreover, you should try these questions yourself, as it will boost your thinking skills.Believe me, most good programmer start by struggling through these silly looking questions

Comment: Homework.......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line = 5
print (line-1) * " " + "* "
for i in xrange(1,line-1):
    print (line-i-1)* " " +  "*" + (2*i -1)*" " + "* "
print (line) * "* "
```

Comment: yes like this, thank you very much