# Draw hollow triangles in Python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I have written the code to draw a filled triangle.

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n-i+1):
        print' ',
    for k in range(1,2*i):
        print'*',
    print
```

Which prints the following pattern(for n=5)

```
      *
    * * *
  * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

However i cannot draw the hollow triangle.

```
      *
    *   *
  *       *
* * * * * * *
```

Here some of the stars are replaced with blank spaces. Anyone can help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make triangle using python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930647/how-to-make-triangle-using-python-2-7)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking to implement a program, and not asking a specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following prints a hollow rectangle:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n-i+1):
        print' ',
    print'*',
    if 1 < i <= n - 1:
        for k in range(1,2*i - 2):
            print' ',
        print'*',
    elif i == n:
        for k in range(1,2*i - 1):
            print'*',
    print
```

The main difference is that, in a filled triangle, there are two stages in each line: the part where you write some spaces and then a part where you write some stars. But in a hollow triangle you need four stages: write spaces, write one star, write zero or more spaces and write one star again. Furthermore, for the last line, you only need to write stars.

Answer (score 0):

Count how many spaces are in each line, and find their relations.
For example, in line 2, the counts of hollow space is 3, in line 3 is 7, and so on.
It can be generalized into that " in line n, the counts of hollow space is 4*n-5"
With this, we can solve this problem by simply three lines of code:

```
for i in range(1,n-1):
     print ' '*(2*n-2*i-2) + "*"+' '*(4*i-5)+"*"*(i!=1)
print '* '*(2*n-3)
```